# Calculate LatLong of point at distance x,y metres from origin LatLong using Boost Geomtry

Tags: boost, geometry, transform

I'm using boost geometry (v1.75) to do forward and reverse coordinate transforms, this works Ok.

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bm = bg::model::d2;


bg::srs::projection<bg::srs::static_epsg<3785> > transform;
bm::point_xy<double, bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree> > origin = { -3.04081, 53.4427}, longLatOut;
bm::point_xy<double, bg::cs::cartesian> xy;
transform.forward(origin, xy);
transform.inverse(xy, longLatOut);
```

I would like calculate a new point as a result of adding an offset x,y metres to my geographic origin (LatLong) - accuracy is important. I'm stuck on how to do this.
Can anyone provide any guidance of the best way to approach this using the boost libs?

Regs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, boost has no cartographic projection function, maybe you can try [PROJ](https://proj.org/) lib.